# Speed comparison between bisect.insort function and list.index and insert function

Tags: python, insert, bisection

As Python doc says, I have thought that bisect module is much faster than list built-in method, index and insert to insert item to long ordered list. So, I simply measure the time expense for both functions, `bisect_func()` and `insert_func()` like below code.

`bisect_func()` score 1.27s and `insert_func()` score 1.38s, which is not a dramatic time difference. My question is that do I miss something to test the efficiency of bisect in this example? Or is bisect not the only efficient approach to insert item into an ordered list?

```
import bisect

HAYSTACK = [n for n in range(100000000)]
NEEDLES = [0, 10, 30, 400, 700, 1000, 1100, 2200, 3600, 32000, 999999]

def bisect_func():
    for needle in reversed(NEEDLES):
        bisect.insort(HAYSTACK, needle)

def insert_func():
    for needle in reversed(NEEDLES):
        position = HAYSTACK.index(needle)
        HAYSTACK.insert(position, needle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start = time.time()
    # bisect_func()
    insert_func()
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: This is not a fair test (I don't know whether it impacts the overall winner) but you should be using `timeit` and not relying on globals

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of [insort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left):

> Insert x in a in sorted order. This is equivalent to
>   a.insert(bisect.bisect_left(a, x, lo, hi), x) assuming that a is
>   already sorted. Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by
>   the slow O(n) insertion step.

The important part is:  *Keep in mind that the O(log n) search is dominated by the slow O(n) insertion step.* So both approaches are *O(n)* at the end, that is why their efficiency is *similar*, with `insort` being slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

Binary search only improves the performance of *finding* the insertion index. It does not improve the *insertion* into the list, which is `O(N)` in both cases and dominates the asymptotic complexity of both functions. Remember that inserting into an array based list needs to shift all elements after the insertion index.